# SingleInstance activity make me confuse

Tags: android

A activity is a singleInstance Activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class A extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("A");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, B.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        testLog("new Intent A");
    }

    private void testLog(String string) {
        Log.d("test", string);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        testLog("destroy A");
    }
}
```

B activity is a standard activity.

In the normal case A->B. User action back operation, and B destroy. User press back again, A destroy. That's correct.

But in the other case: A->B. User action home button. When user restart task, the android framework calls A's `onNewIntent()`.

Why?I mean the activity stack should like that:

```
-B
-A
```

Why does the android framework route the intent to A?

Comment: Would you mind posting your manifest? I think you're having it as default on the launcher.

Comment: Better yet, just answer: is "A" the default/launcher activity in your manifest?

Comment: The android manifest is very simple.Like that:<activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name=".task.A" />
<activity android:launchMode="standard" android:name=".task.B" />

Comment: No,A is not the default launcher.

Comment: Please wait as I'm writing an answer as I believe I'm fully aware of what you are thinking and why you can't understand the answer that is already written below.

Comment: Ok, read the answer and see if that clears your mind a bit...

Comment: My suggestion: go back to Eclipse and experiment with various launch modes before asking. It's quicker and you'll learn faster than asking here. Besides, try the "Activities LaunchMod" app from the market. It's a developers app that shows how this all works.

Answer (score 4):

There are differences between `singleTop`, `singleTask` and `singleInstance`. Read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode) for more information, but you do want to note the description of `singleInstance`.

> Only allow one instance of this activity to ever be running. **This activity gets a unique task with only itself running in it; if it is ever launched again with the same Intent, then that task will be brought forward and its Activity.onNewIntent() method called.** If this activity tries to start a new activity, that new activity will be launched in a separate task. See the Tasks and Back Stack document for more details about tasks.

This is exactly the behavior you're seeing and should be expected.

Comment: Well,Ok.But I still have a question.In the home case,B is the foreground(task).Why android route to A(Which is background task)?

Comment: As David mentions, I think you probably should do a bit more reading to understand tasks. The recommendation in the quote is probably a good one. Take a look at the [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) doc.

Answer (score 2):

OK, now that you answered that comment I can answer your question feeling more safe about it.

What kabuko said is right. However, you're not understanding it because you don't even understand the concept of tasks, and how that relates to the launcher.

When you have a `singleInstance` activity being started at the launcher (see? that's why I asked about your manifest!), the launcher is **not** launching/restarting whatever activities you started/used with Activity A (a `singleInstance` activity). It's starting/restarting the A's **task** as it was left.

In fact, as the documentation says (read kabuko's answer), when you launch B from A, B is considered a new task altogether. It just happens that those two activities are "glued" together in the activity history... obviously, since you start B right after starting A. But I say again: **it's important to see that this constitutes a logical break into your application.**

And why is that a logical break, you ask?

Because A is a `singleInstance` activity. And as already said here, those are the one and only one activity in that task. So, if you start that **task** again from the launcher, you will end up at A again, and not B since B is another task that does not belong to A.

Compare to what you were expecting: if A were a `standard`, B would be started and considered in the same task. Therefore, restarting A's **task** would end up in B, which is what you were expecting.

Finally, as the doc says, this is the reason why you mostly always should not use `singleTask` and even less `singleInstance`. Those are not the expected behavior. And since they are not for you, they will be even less for the user, everything else equal.

Comment: As I said: if the launcher *had* A as default, the launcher would call A, and the recents would call the activity on top (even B), considering you didn't finish B yet (in this case, would be A). If A is *not* the default/launcher, then the launcher would call B (not A's task, which is different from the launcher's task in manifest) and the recents would call A if that's where you left off. It's all about tasks and the manifest, and the difference between recents and the launcher.

Comment: I have post some append question,wish you will tell me more details.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
android:taskAffinity="" android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```