# Android windowIsTranslucent locks orientation to portrait

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-task

I have an activity which i would like launched using:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

I do not understand why on handset devices the orientation is locked to portrait and on tablet it is not. When i remove this flag the orientation is available both on handsets and tablets.

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821680/2746924

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394582/singleinstance-activity-make-me-confuse

Comment: Read it top to bottom. Nothing there answers my question.

Comment: @JY2k wow you are getting the worst answers today

Comment: @JY2k try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101459/androidtheme-translucent-locks-orientation-to-portrait

Comment: This correct answer is explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3821680/2746924

Comment: I think this might be what you were looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17638005/453052